# ASP.NET Core web-приложение

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

у меня на работе в связи с безопасностью установили Visual Studio на виртуальную машину, мне нужно сделать приложение(я никогда с этим не работала) проект создаю "веб-приложение (модель-контроллер)",[image: введите сюда описание изображения] но при запуске в обозревателе решений написано "Решение "название решения" (проектов: 0) и нету ни одного компонента[image: введите сюда описание изображения], а при запуске должно быть написано IIS (в видео на Ютубе было так) и должно открываться окно как в браузере пока что пустое, а у меня же вместо этого на стрелочка написано "присоединение"[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и принажатие открывается не окно а присоединение к процессу[image: введите сюда описание изображения] я например выбираю что-то и ничего только идёт обработка.
Так же в меню выбираю фаил и хочу изменить параметры страницы, но этот пункт не активен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же на главном экране какая-то ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Устанавливала не я так что не могу понять причины, изменить или переустановить что-то тоже не могу, у меня нету доступа, вопрос заключается в том, это проблема с программой, как-то не так установили или я туплю? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через пуск переходишь в переменные среды, находишь PATH. Строку C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\ помещаешь ниже строки C:\Program Files\dotnet. Лично это решило эту проблему у меня.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тебя прям обожаю, лучший человек

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обновить или переустановить vs на более новой версии всё работает